# SQL - need a query to get all distinct message threads given a userID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple messaging schema where each message has a senderFK and a recipientFK, each mapping to a user record. For the current user, I need to get all distinct threads. A distinct thread is the either the senderFK or the recipientFK for the user who has either sent or received a message.

So, for example:

This query gets all users who sent a message to the current user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT senderFK AS threadID FROM Messages
WHERE recipientFK = 'usr_developer'
```

This query gets all users who have received a message from the current user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipientFK AS threadID FROM Messages
WHERE senderFK = 'usr_developer'
```

How would I combine these queries into a single table that has a distinct row for each user and a single column (threadID)?

Comment: If Michael's UNION isn't what you were looking for can you show a few sample rows of what you want?  If it's the right result, please accept it.  When you do a UNION, any rows where the values in all columns (the one column in this case) are duplicates only appear once in the output.  And it sounds like that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT recipientFK as UserId, senderFK as ThreadID
 FROM Messages
UNION
SELECT senderFK as UserID, recipientFK AS threadID
 FROM Messages
```

This method leaves out user filters based on your comment `...a distinct row for each user ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT senderFK AS threadID 
FROM Messages
WHERE recipientFK = 'usr_developer'

UNION

SELECT recipientFK AS threadID 
FROM Messages
WHERE senderFK = 'usr_developer'
```

Note that you don't need `DISTINCT` anymore, since `UNION` will filter out any duplicates.

Comment: Yea, no need for the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server, you can do something like the following:

```
select distinct case when senderFK = 'usr_developer' then recipientFK else senderFK end ThreadID
from Messages
where 'usr_developer' in (senderFK, recipientFK)
```

Equally you can change the WHERE clause if you prefer/it outperforms:

```
select distinct case when senderFK = 'usr_developer' then recipientFK else senderFK end ThreadID
from Messages
where senderFK = 'usr_developer' 
   or recipientFK = 'usr_developer'
```